# ASP.NET Web Site (WSP) - Precompile - how to use an alternate folder

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-compiler

How can I instruct an ASP.net website to use an alternate precompiled folder instead of the default `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\Temporary ASP.NET Files`?

I know how to use `aspnet_compiler.exe` and specify `TargetPath` but then I see that when I access the website for the first time, it still precompiles to `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

Update: I'm trying to achieve "in-place precompilation" as per this article [Precompiling Your Website (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web.config, you can set:

`<compilation tempDirectory="D:\TempASP.NET">`

For documentation on [compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.compilationsection) section, see reference.